# How to create graphic slider in Python that can be modified with mouse?

Tags: python, slider, pyqt, progress-bar

How can i create a graphic slider similar to a progress bar in PyQt that can be modified from 0 to 100 with mouse?

[image]

Comment: Not sure I'm getting it right... are you looking for a solution without PyQt that looks like PyQt? Or just a PyQt slider?

Comment: I just need slider. PyQt is not neccessary

Comment: Well, if you have PyQt - what about the `QSlider`? °°

Comment: As i understand it creates slider with some control point. And i need graphic slider like on picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set QSlider stylesheet appropriately. This solution is based on PyQt5

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

class MyApp(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()                
        self.mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        self.slider = QtWidgets.QSlider()
        self.slider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider.setStyleSheet(self.stylesheet())

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.slider)
        self.mainWidget.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def stylesheet(self):
        return """
            QSlider::groove:horizontal {
                background: white;
                height: 40px;
            }

            QSlider::sub-page:horizontal {
                background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0,    x2: 0, y2: 1,
                    stop: 0 #66e, stop: 1 #bbf);
                background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0.2, x2: 1, y2: 1,
                    stop: 0 #bbf, stop: 1 #55f);
                height: 40px;
            }

            QSlider::add-page:horizontal {
                background: #fff;
                height: 40px;
            }

            QSlider::handle:horizontal {
                background: #bbf;
                border: 0px;
                width: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
                border-radius: 0px;
            }
        """

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MyApp()
```

and this is the output component

[image]

Comment: Thank you for help. But can you explain what is it the type of code after defining stylesheet?

Comment: @user3664471: only a comment. You can draw your control point with an image. I've removed it.

Comment: But when i delete it - sliders returns standart. Not like yours

Comment: @user3664471 : What have you comment out? Follow the posted code. I have edit my post and the extra comment is not more present. I tested it. It works fine.

Comment: Due to my low experience in Python i mean that i don't understand the code after return function """ . And if i delete it - it returns standart,non graphic slider. So i dont want to terror you with questions. Can you just explain where did you learn that type of code or do i have to read any manuals?

Comment: @user3664471 : between the first """ and the last """ there is your slider's stylesheet. If you remove it you see a normal slider. More info about this topics on Qt documentation.