# pyside2 Implement an input box with a slider visual

Tags: pyside2

I want to implement a blender-like property adjustment box with pyside2 in Autodesk Maya, as shown below.

[image]

I have found some similar links, but without success specifically how to do it.
[How to create graphic slider in Python that can be modified with mouse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077760/how-to-create-graphic-slider-in-python-that-can-be-modified-with-mouse)

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QEvent
from PySide2.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTableView, QHBoxLayout, QStyledItemDelegate, QStyle, QStyleOptionProgressBar, QStyleOptionButton

class MyTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTableView, self).__init__()


class MyDelgate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyDelgate, self).__init__()


    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.column() == 1:
            style = QStyleOptionProgressBar()
            style.minimum = 0
            style.maximum = 10
            style.progress= index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
            style.rect = option.rect
            QApplication.style().drawControl(QStyle.CE_ProgressBar, style, painter)

        elif index.column() == 2:
            style = QStyleOptionButton()
            if index.data(Qt.DisplayRole) == True:
                style.state = QStyle.State_On
            else:
                style.state = QStyle.State_Off
            style.state |= QStyle.State_Enabled
            style.rect = option.rect
            style.rect.setX(option.rect.x() + option.rect.width() / 2 - 7)
            QApplication.style().drawControl(QStyle.CE_CheckBox, style, painter)
        else:
            return QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)

    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        if index.column() == 2:
            if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress and option.rect.contains(event.pos()):
                data = not index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
                model.setData(index, data, Qt.DisplayRole)
            return True
        else:
            return QStyledItemDelegate.editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index)

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

        self.mode = QStandardItemModel()
        root = self.mode.invisibleRootItem()

        item1 = QStandardItem()
        item1.setData('a', Qt.DisplayRole)

        item2 = QStandardItem()
        item2.setData(1, Qt.DisplayRole)

        item3 = QStandardItem()
        item3.setData(False, Qt.DisplayRole)

        item4 = QStandardItem()
        item4.setData('b', Qt.DisplayRole)

        item5 = QStandardItem()
        item5.setData(2, Qt.DisplayRole)

        item6 = QStandardItem()
        item6.setData(True, Qt.DisplayRole)

        root.setChild(0, 0, item1)
        root.setChild(0, 1, item2)
        root.setChild(0, 2, item3)
        root.setChild(1, 0, item4)
        root.setChild(1, 1, item5)
        root.setChild(1, 2, item6)

        tableView = MyTableView()
        tableView.setModel(self.mode)
        tableView.setItemDelegate(MyDelgate())

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(tableView)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.resize(500, 300)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track the mouse position in the `editorEvent` and compute the ratio based on the sub element rectangle of the style option.

```py
    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        if index.column() == 1:
            if event.type() in (event.MouseMove, event.MouseButtonPress):
                progressOpt = QStyleOptionProgressBar()
                progressOpt.rect = option.rect
                style = option.widget.style()
                rect = style.subElementRect(style.SE_ProgressBarGroove,
                    progressOpt, option.widget)
                pos = max(0, min(rect.width(), event.x() - rect.x()))
                model.setData(index, round(pos / rect.width() * 10), Qt.DisplayRole)
                return True
        elif index.column() == 2:
            if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress and option.rect.contains(event.pos()):
                data = not index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
                model.setData(index, data, Qt.DisplayRole)
            return True
        return super().editorEvent(event, model, option, index)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot for your help.
Can I make the values appear on top like on the gif image above? As I slide this control with the mouse, the value is dynamically updated.

Comment: You must set the option `text` property in the `paint` method.

Comment: Can you help me with a code example, I tried it without success, forgive me for being a pyqt beginner.
Thank you so much.

Comment: @chenzhiwei [`text`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptionprogressbar.html#text-var) is a *variable* of QStyleOptionProgressBar, you need to set it (`style.text = 'some text'`) before calling `drawControl()`. You also need to set the `textVisible` variable to `True`. Dealing with QStyle is not immediate, but can be done easily if you understand its elements.

Comment: @chenzhiwei also remember that when an answer solves your question, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the gray tick mark on its left. Please take your time to review the [tour] to understand how StackOverflow works.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I will try again following your tips.